# On click show or hide the children links in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a help for the side menu navigation.

On click of main menu "Divisions" link, i should show the child elements, which are link1, link2, link3 etc.

If i click again main menu "Divisions" link,child items should be hided (link1, link2, link3 should be Hided).

I have tried so far in javascript

```
var x = document.getElementById("p968").className = "classToKeep";
```

and CSS to hide

```
.classToKeep{
      color:#fff;
      }
       .classToKeep ul{
      display:none;
      }
```

But not succesful, How to do that in jquery or Javascript.

Can ayone help on this Please.

Please check this
**JS FIDDLE Link:** [**http://jsfiddle.net/a3x004fs/**](http://jsfiddle.net/a3x004fs/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="vlist">
  <li id="p968" class="active">
    <strong>Divisions</strong>
    <ul>
      <li id="p981"><a href="link1.html" >link1</a></li>
      <li id="p982"><a href="link2.html" >link2</a></li>
      <li id="p983"><a href="link3.html" >link3</a></li>
      <li id="p1064"><a href="link4.html" >link4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="p969"><a href="#">mainlink2</a></li>
  <li id="p96955"><a href="#">mainlin3</a></li>
  <li id="p989"><a href="#">mainlink4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
@media all
{
    /* title */
    h6.vlist {
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:100%;
        width:90%;
        padding:3px 0px 3px 10%; /* LTR */
        margin:0;
        color:#444;
        background-color:#fff;
        border-top:2px #ddd solid;
        border-bottom:4px #888 solid;
    }

    .vlist {
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0 0 1.5em 0;
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    .vlist ul {
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .vlist li {
        float:left; /* LTR */
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .vlist a,
    .vlist strong,
    .vlist span {
        display:block;
        padding:3px 0px 3px 10%;
        text-decoration:none;
        border-bottom:1px #ddd solid;
    }

    .vlist a,
    .vlist a:visited {
        color:#444;
        text-decoration: none;
    }



    /* active list element */
    .vlist li.active {
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#800;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    /* Level 1 */
    .vlist li a,
    .vlist li strong,
    .vlist li span { width:95%; padding-left:5%; } /* LTR */

    .vlist li a:focus,
    .vlist li a:hover,
    .vlist li a:active { background-color:#a88; color:#fff; outline: 0 none; }

    /* Level 2 */
    .vlist li ul li a,
    .vlist li ul li strong,
    .vlist li ul li span { width:95%; padding-left:5%; } /* LTR */

    .vlist li ul li a, 
    .vlist li ul li a:visited { background-color:#f8f8f8; color:#333; }
    .vlist li ul li a:focus,
    .vlist li ul li a:hover,
    .vlist li ul li a:active { background-color:#a88; color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do add script jQuery to your head tag

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

You can use jQuery to show hide menu.

```
$('li').on('click',function(e){
    var that = $(this);
    if(that.parents('ul').length>1){
        e.stopPropagation()
        return true;
    }else if(that.find('ul').length>0){
        that.toggleClass('classToKeep')
    }
});
```

#### Edit 2:

Completely forgot you actually have to click the children `<li>` elements. Ok the code is same just if it is a children li just dont let the event propagate to the 
parent thats all. Updated Fiddle

Working DEMO : [Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0q9x6k3w/4/)

Comment: updated fiddle in the answer. Somehow the js was not sticking

Comment: @joyBlanks thank you friend. I will check now and get back to you

Comment: @joyBlanks unfortunatelly it is working in jsfiddle, not in website ERROR:Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Do add script jQuery to your head tag

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa did it work after adding the script?

Comment: @joyBlanks: It's better to give the latest plugins than the older ones. Here you are giving **2.1.1** which might not support all the jquery features. If not added try adding this one `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: @joyBlanks, here if i click " link1" , the "Divisions" is closing. Can you check the fiddle please

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa: Completely forgot you actually have to click the children `<li>` elements. Ok the code is same just if it is a children li just dont let the event propagate to the parent thats all. check Updated Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
You can simply use toggl function of jquery:- 



$("#p968").toggle(function () {
        $('#tackle').hide();
    }, function () {
        $('#tackle').show();
    });

<ul class="vlist">
    <li id="p968" class="active"><strong>Divisions</strong>
        <ul id="tackle">
            <li id="p981"><a href="link1.html">link1</a></li>
            <li id="p982"><a href="link2.html">link2</a></li>
            <li id="p983"><a href="link3.html">link3</a></li>
            <li id="p1064"><a href="link4.html">link4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="p969"><a href="#">mainlink2</a></li>
    <li id="p96955"><a href="#">mainlin3</a></li>
    <li id="p989"><a href="#">mainlink4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: did you checked the code which you posted as an answer?

Comment: Have u added this -1    :-)

Comment: Am new learner in jquery ....You can ask problem directly also...That would be like learning for me ... :-)

Comment: @Codeshow, here if i click link1 also the "Divisions" is closing. Can you  check the fiddle please

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to simple add a class to display your ´li's´ you had previusly hidden with `display:none`and then add this jquery:

```
$('.active').click(function () {
                $('.link').toggleClass("hidden"); 
            });
```

I have added to class "link" to the `li's`you want to be hidden.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/a3x004fs/3/)**

Comment: thank you for the answer. But small issue, when i am in link1 (children), it is not closing the  'divisions'.
Can you please help me here http://jsfiddle.net/a3x004fs/5/

Comment: I don't understand your comment mate. Whatever you click on link1, link2, link3, link4 or divisions all the links are hidden well

Comment: Sorry mate .  If i click "link1" it should not close "Divisions". << it should close only divisions are clicked  >>

Comment: That's easy. I just wrapped the "divisions" text in a `div` with a class and changed the `jquery` so you open and close just when clicking in this `div`insteed of the "active" whole `li`: http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/a3x004fs/6/

Answer (score 1):

Add this both code block for css and JS in your code.

```
.classToKeep{
     color:#fff;
  }
   .classToKeep ul{
      display:none;
  } 

$("#p968").click(function(){   
   $(this).toggleClass("classToKeep")
});
```

Comment: here if i click link1 also the "Divisions" is closing. Can you check the fiddle please

Comment: It is because those child li are inside parent li with id="p968". So for that you got to change your HTML structure just a little bit by placing "Divisions" text in span tag inside parent li tag and perform child hide/show operation on that. 

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1yLpoctd/